# Add single field on df end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible after dataframe with 20+ rows and xx+ columns to add a single field with total count of certain value. User will add different values to df and before 'pandas.DataFrame.to_excel' it's neccesary to  to add a single field with some specific data. Like in the attached picture. Is it possible to add a single field after an already structured df?

[image]

Comment: what do you want added to the other columns?

Comment: 'NaN'. Problem is solved below, it's works exactly as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can work for you:

Df:

```
               A    B  output
0              a  1.0     1.0
1              a  2.0     1.0
2              a  3.0     1.0
3              a  4.0     1.0
4              a  5.0     1.0

for i in range(df.iloc[-1].name + 1, 25): # Add 20 new nan row (you can change it) 
    df.loc[i, :] = np.nan

df.loc[df.iloc[-1].name + 1, 'A'] = 'Result: ' + str(df['B'].sum()) # For this example i just put sum of column B so you can change it.
print(df)

               A    B  output
0              a  1.0     1.0
1              a  2.0     1.0
2              a  3.0     1.0
3              a  4.0     1.0
4              a  5.0     1.0
5            NaN  NaN     NaN
6            NaN  NaN     NaN
7            NaN  NaN     NaN
8            NaN  NaN     NaN
9            NaN  NaN     NaN
10           NaN  NaN     NaN
11           NaN  NaN     NaN
12           NaN  NaN     NaN
13           NaN  NaN     NaN
14           NaN  NaN     NaN
15           NaN  NaN     NaN
16           NaN  NaN     NaN
17           NaN  NaN     NaN
18           NaN  NaN     NaN
19           NaN  NaN     NaN
20           NaN  NaN     NaN
21           NaN  NaN     NaN
22           NaN  NaN     NaN
23           NaN  NaN     NaN
24           NaN  NaN     NaN
25  Result: 15.0  NaN     NaN
```